# Why Blender Mesh becomes messy when imported into Salome

Tags: mesh

I have created simple geometry in Blender-two concentric curved cylinders. In the edit mode, it looks okay. But when I import the STL file in Salome, a preprocessing software, the mesh become triangular and more dense. Why is this case? Anyone knows?Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, some (most ?) 3D softwares don't support polygons with more than 3 vertices. Your mesh was automatically converted to all triangles because it had a certain number of N-Gons

Comment: so how can i avoid this? thanks.

Comment: You won't prevent the quads turning into 2 triangles, but you can tidy up the cap by using quad topology there

Comment: @Gorgious I have been able to do what you say. But still have some little problem as shown in my answer area. Please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the cap fill type of the cylinder to be triangle fan. It looks nicer. But the imported STL file in Salome still has some weird small redundant edges...

[image]
[image]

[image]

After I have cleaned up the mesh by merging by distance. Then the final geometry looks nice in Salome:
[image]

Comment: Are tou talking about the white grid pattern ? You may have double geometry there, check in edit mode if you have double vertices on the same place

Comment: You have reminded me! In edit mode, I have cleaned up the mesh by merging by distance. Then the final geometry looks nice in Salome. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it all worked out :)